# Will get married vs getting married

Tags: tense, present-tense

I am little bit confused about these sentences. Both are correct. We can use continuous tense for future meaning but one of my teachers said it sounds funny.

Which one is correct and why with reason?

> I will get married next week..
>
> I'm getting married next week..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English has several forms of grammar to show the future. They're mostly interchangeable, but there are a few differences.

We usually use 'will + verb' for predictions, 'be going to + verb' for predictions based on current information and future plans, and the present progressive ('be + verb-ing') for scheduled future plans.

- I will get married next week. The fortune teller said so.
- I'm going to get married next week. I can hardly wait!
- I'm getting married next week, so the bachelor party has to be this weekend.

Whether it's a prediction or not depends on if you have control over it.

- It will rain today. (no control; prediction)
- It's going to rain today. (no control; prediction)
- It's raining today. (not a prediction; ungrammatical if trying to state the future but fine if describing current weather conditions)

Comment: Your answer is great, although there is one little mistake - Saying _It's raining today_ isn't ungrammatical, unless you are referring directly to the future tense, which may be misunderstood with the continous form of the present tense. Edit your answer and increase these little details so that you won't get the OP confused, I know he has already seen this construction and may get confused. After you edit +1

Comment: @DavydDiniz done

Answer (score 1):

> I will get married next week.
>
> I'm getting married next week..

Both constructions work fine, people generally use "*Am/Is/Are getting married next week*" (The second example) when talking about something that has been planned for a long time or you have thought about, and will certainly happen beyond a shadow of doubt, i.e, this future event will happen *no matter what happens*. You use this construction when you are 100% sure that nothing can either interrupt or delay it.

> I'm getting married tomorrow no matter what happens!
>
> My parents are arriving tomorrow.
>
> I'm searching for jobs tomorrow
>
> He is working next week.

-

> I will get married next week if it doesn't rain.
>
> My parents will arrive tomorrow if the whether is fine.
>
> I will search for jobs tomorrow if I'm not tired.
>
> He will work next week if he is feeling better.

As you can see, all these constructions were increased *if*, which implies to say one condition, *something would happen if another thing happens*: *If it doesn't rain*, *If the whether is fine*, *If I'm not tired*, *If he is feeling better*.

So baseed on these examples, I would certainly say that "**I'm + verb ING**" is placed in a *high degree of sureless*, i.e, only used when you are totally sure about one the occurrence of a future action.

You can also enjoy using this construction to express a future action, formed by: *Subject + Will + To be + Verb -ING*:

> I will be doing this next week
>
> He will be working next week
>
> They will be traveling next week.

Answer (score -1):

"I will get married next week" means that you have aplan to marrage, but you are not in progress of wedding.

I am getting married" means you are now in progress of wedding....

Insteady of "getting married"
you can say " going to get married".

will- future possibility, the fulfilmen of condition is depends on the goodness of the situation of the future...you may not be get married if the situation will not good.

getting/going to - future certainity that you have a plan and also you are under the process to achive your goal.... You are in progress of your wedding now....

Comment: _I'm getting married next week_ also works, and this is the construction of the future tense by using -ING. *It's used to talk about an arrangement that has already been planned or you have already thought about*. = _I'm getting married next week_ - _We are traveling tomorrow_  - My parents are arriving tomorrow_: Subject + To be in the present tense + Verb -ING.

You can also use the form of the verb *To Be + -ING*: _I will be getting married tomorrow_ - My parents will be arriving tomorrow_: Subject + Will + Verb To Be + Verb -ING.