# Is coming or comes

Tags: present-tense

Do native speakers use present continuous when talking about timetables? Can I use "is coming" in my sentence?

> That film comes/is coming to the local cinema next week. Do you want to see it?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't mentioned in any book.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114799/will-get-married-vs-getting-married

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common part of most books on English grammar.  For example The [BBC world service language learning](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode73/languagepoint.shtml)  states

> English speakers often use the present continuous tense (subject + 'be' = verb-ing) to talk about future arrangements.

A movie timetable is a future arrangement, and it would be normal and natural to use present continuous in this situation.  This is re-enforced by idiom.  Movie trailers often say "Coming soon to a theatre near you!"

Comment: But if I am talking about train, plane, bus, etc or a lesson, can I say "The train/bus is leaving at 5"  "The plane is taking off at 6" and "The lesson is starting at 4"?

Comment: Yes. What applies to a cinema timetable applies equally to a school or transport timetable.